# What personal computer GUI paradigms exists?

Tags: gui-design

I am referring to what people would call "desktop" or "workbench" or "windowing system", but since those words are biased, I didn't put them in the title, but I mentioned now so people can understand the question.

I want to know, what sort of "desktop" GUIs that exist, beside OSX-style with docks, files that can save their own visual position inside a window, folders that can save their window itself, and so on, and Windows style, with "start menu", desktop icons, and files and folders organized in a table or in a grid.

I want to know the names and descriptions of things academically, not pointing to a specific program.

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to know what type of GUIs exist for _desktop computing systems_, that are not only **not** Mac OS or Windows systems, but also **_different_** to these in that they do **not** use a dock, task bar, menus like the Apple Menu or Start Menu, icons etc? Or, are you after GUIs that are not Mac OS and Windows (e.g. NeXT, BeOS, Ambient, Cinnamon, Sugar, Trinity, etc). And, are you after only what has been and is available, or also after future concepts as well?

Comment: I want to know what GUIs has been attempted in the past, present, and current research for the future (not just theoretical speculation, since that would be even broader...), for desktop computers, not only the obvious (Win/OSX and Linux managers) but other more academic ones, or ones that failed for some reason or another (like that Jurassic Park Unix thing).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment